# copula and categorical data transformation

Tags: categorical-data, data-transformation, copula

I plan to model copulas with data that has categorical variables. Copula modeling with categorical variables requires a transformation of categorical variables into continuous (link: [https://hal.science/hal-03188317/document#:~:text=Categorical%20data%20cannot%20be%20modeled,values%20of%20a%20categorical%20variable](https://hal.science/hal-03188317/document#:%7E:text=Categorical%20data%20cannot%20be%20modeled,values%20of%20a%20categorical%20variable). at page 7).

**I have a question**: Is it okay if, after transforming the categorical variable into continuous according to the steps in the link above, I only use some of the levels contained in the categorical variable and not all of them? For example, the vehclass variable has seven levels, namely a, b, c, d, e, f, and g; then, to create the copula model, I only use the vehclass variable with levels a, b, c. It would be very helpful if you could include the source of the reasoning for the answer.